# How to run math action/function from a list in a specific order at any called time, one by one

Tags: java

I'm trying to build an algorithm in java, which in ugly way looks like this:

```
while (true) {
    Point p; //a point given in the class constuctor.
    p.x+=1*factor;
    checkColor(p); // a function that returns true or false for a pixel color.
    p.y+=1*factor;
    checkColor(p);
    p.x-=2*factor;
    checkColor(p);
    p.y-=*factor;
    ... ...
}
```

This will use a int factor; that will increase every cycle in the loop,
but my point is if there is a way to store a 'line of actions' that will be executed 1 line at a time, when I call a a function.

Comment: I'm not sure about others, but I'm very confused on just what it is you're trying to do. A little context would go a long way towards clearing this up for me and perhaps others.

Comment: I also don't understand what's your intention.

Comment: heh looks like the Fibonacci Sequence with alternating sign every 2 iterations

Comment: "This will use a int factor; that will rise every one circle..." Please translate this into English assuming that we don't have the slightest clue about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm running a color search around the point given, using a loop code that needs to set 2 different variables at different times in but same order again and again, managed by a variable 'factor'.
I'm tired, excuse me for my poor grammar =S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about doing something like this:

```
private processSequence = 0;
public void modifyPoint(Point p, int factor) {
  // do the stuff you need to do with x and y
  switch (processSequence) {
     case 0: p.x+= factor; break;
     case 1: p.y+=factor; break;
     ... etc
  }
  processSequence++;
  processSequence = processSequence % 4; 
}


...
while (true) {
  modifyPoint(p,factor);
  checkColor(p);
}
```

what you actually want to do is not easy to understand from the question it
self.

Comment: Sorry for my poor grammar, I'm really tired.
And yes, that will work
Not the exact thing I needed, but I can work it out.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A SWAG since I still don't have a clue what you're trying to do, but maybe something like...

```
  Point p = new Point(/* something? */);
  for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
     for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
        if (i != 0 || j != 0) {
           Point p2 = new Point(p.x + i * factor, p.y + i * factor);
           checkColor(p2);
        }
     }
  }
```